# How to get variable names in Mathematica timeseries?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8, mathematical-expressions

I am using the predefined "WindSpeedData" function, which returns a TimeSeries object. How can I get the variable names that constitute the time series and their corresponding data?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.
Use "Values[WindspeedData[...]] "